ThorLabs Piezo Motor Controller with pylablib
I have a query regarding the TIM1010 Piezo Motor Controller. I am trying to integrate this device into a python script using pylablib but am having difficulty with it.
I can connect a piezo to the controller and can have it be recognised by python by sending the following command:
from pylablib.devices import Thorlabs
motor = Thorlabs.KinesisPiezoMotor("XXXXX")

However I get the following error:

UserWarning: model number TIM101 doesn't match the device ID prefix
65(TIM001) warnings.warn("model number {} doesn't match the device ID
prefix {}({})".format(model_no,port,port_model_no))

I can also get the following command to work:
motor.blink()

However when I try the following, errors are returned:
motor._pzctl_enable_channel(1)


Error: ThorlabsBackendError: backend exception: 'read returned less
data than expected' ('read returned less data than expected')

motor._pzmot_jog(direction = "+", kind = "continuous", channel = 1)


Error:  unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes

I only want to jog this piezo back and forth, so quite simple control is all that is needed. Any advice or guidance would be appreciated

TIM101 does not equal TIM001.

Yes but the TIM001 does not exist as a piece of equipment
